# Problem getting function to run for a specific amount of time

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a function in python for a specific amount of time (say 100 sec), and then move on to run another function for a specific amount of time.

I've tried creating a counter and using while counter < (some frame number). I've also tried using datetime by doing something like
        end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=100)
        while datetime.now() < end_time:
These things don't seem to be working and I don't know why.
Here is my current version of the code:

```py
class FicTracAout90deg(object):

   def run(self, gain_yaw = 1):

        end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
        while datetime.now() < end_time:

            for item in self.pubsub.listen():

                message = item['data']
                try:
                    data = json.loads(message)
                except TypeError:
                    continue

                if data['type'] == 'reset':                  
                    self.time_start = time.time()
                    self.heading_rate_calc.reset(self.time_start)

                else:
                    time_curr = time.time()
                    heading = data['heading']
                    intx = data['intx']
                    inty = data['inty']
                    velx = data['velx']
                    vely = data['vely']
                    velheading = data['deltaheading']
                    self.accum_heading += velheading
                    self.accum_x += velx
                    self.accum_y += vely
                    time_elapsed = time_curr - self.time_start
```

I'm running this with the following code:

```
from analogoutNoise import FicTracAoutNoise
from analogout90deg import FicTracAout90deg
import time

#for a certain amount of time run block 1
#Block 1
for x in range(2):
         client = FicTracAout90deg()
         client.run(1)
```

The 'run' function never seems to stop, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html This library is designed for asynchronous execution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "don't seem to be working" is not a problem specification.  Where is your trace of the loop control values, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the issue is that the line `for item in self.pubsub.listen():` never returns a value and so it doesn't finish executing.  If this statement doesn't finish execution then the rest of the code is not run and the outer loop is not checked.

Answer (score -1):

Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). In order to get your script to run, I had to add `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`. The following code *does* work, and is similar structurally to yours:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

tBegin = datetime.now()
tEnd = tBegin + timedelta(seconds=100)

while datetime.now() < tEnd:
    print(datetime.now())
    sleep(10)

print(datetime.now())
```

Since this works, it seems to me that the problem is not with the time endpoints, but rather with the internals of your `while` loop. It can perform a very large number of iterations in 100 sec., which means it's pinning the processor for all that time and accumulating a lot of garbage. It's probably better to think up a different approach, as @iamchoosinganame suggested.

Comment: While a different approach may be a better choice, it would be more helpful to describe another approach rather than just telling OP to find one.  Or just to skip the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My answer addresses the original question: "These things don't seem to be working and I don't know why." Coming up with alternatives is beyond the scope of the question and drifts into discussion territory.